# N-queens multithreaded working time

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, n-queens

I coded a linear (without threads) app, which looks ok and has normal solving speed. Also, I coded a multithreaded app, and it is ok when I use 2 processors and 2 threads. It is also fine when I use 4 processors and 4 threads. But when I try to solve with 6 processors and 6 threads, I am not satisfied with the solving speed. How can I make it faster?

**Main.java:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Iveskite N:");
        //int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
         int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         int maxThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         Karalienes.setMaxGSK(maxThreads);
        Karalienes queens = new Karalienes(n, 1, new int[n+1]);
        long startedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        queens.start();
        queens.join();
        System.out.println("Solutions: "+Karalienes.getVariantuSkaiciu());
        //queens.print();
        System.out.println("Working time: "+(float)(System.currentTimeMillis()-startedTime)/1000
                + " s.");
    }
}
```

**Karalienes.java:**

```
import java.util.Stack;


public class Karalienes extends Thread {
    private int n;
    private int places[];
    private int column;
    private static Integer solutions = new Integer(0);
    private static Integer startedThreads = 0;
    private static int maxThreads;
    private Stack<Karalienes> stack;

    public Karalienes(int n,int column, int places[]) {
        this.n = n;
        this.column = column;
        this.places = places;
        stack = new Stack<Karalienes>();
    }

    public static void setMaxGSK(int sk) {
        this.maxThreads = sk;
    }

    private boolean arOk(int row, int column) {
        boolean ok = true;
        int tmpColumn = column-1;
        for(; tmpColumn>=1; tmpColumn--) {
            if ((places[tmpColumn]-row)==0) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }

            int rowDiff = places[column] - places[tmpColumn];

            if (rowDiff < 0)
                rowDiff = 0 - rowDiff;

            if (rowDiff == column-tmpColumn) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }       
        }
        return ok;
    }
    public void deliojam() {
        for(int i=1; i<=n ; i++ ) { //dirbam su row
            places[column] = i;
            if (arOk(i, column)) {
                if (column<n) {
                    int gSk;
                    synchronized (startedThreads) {
                        gSk = startedThreads;
                    }
                    if (gSk < maxThreads) {
                        Karalienes kar = new Karalienes(n, column+1, places.clone());
                        kar.start();
                        stack.add(kar);
                    }
                    else {
                        column++;
                        deliojam();
                        column--;
                    }
                }
                if (column==n) {
                    Karalienes.incVariantuSkaiciu();
                }
            }   
        }

        while (stack.size()!=0) {
            try {
                stack.pop().join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Karalienes.incGijuSk();
        deliojam();
        Karalienes.decGijuSk();
    }

    private static synchronized void incVariantuSkaiciu() {
        solutions++;
    }

    private static synchronized void incGijuSk() {
        startedThreads++;
    }

    private static synchronized void decGijuSk() {
        startedThreads--;
    }
    public static int getVariantuSkaiciu() {
        return solutions;
    }
}
```

**List of times:**

> ```
> Computer (code with threads)          
> Proc  Threads N   Working time (in seconds)
> 2 2   9   0,022
> 2 2   10  0,052
> 2 2   11  0,106
> 2 2   12  0,299
> 2 2   13  1,342
> 2 2   14  7,303
> 2 2   15  47,486
> 2 2   16  345,369
> 2 2   17  2702,898
> 4 4   9   0,043
> 4 4   10  0,067
> 4 4   11  0,135
> 4 4   12  0,438
> 4 4   13  1,609
> 4 4   14  7,146
> 4 4   15  42,196
> 4 4   16  293,293
> 4 4   17  2038,762
> 6 6   9   0,053
> 6 6   10  0,09
> 6 6   11  0,194
> 6 6   12  0,483
> 6 6   13  1,99
> 6 6   14  10,347
> 6 6   15  62,086
> 6 6   16  420,496
> 6 6   17  2915,52
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably encountering locking between threads, where the `synchronized` between threads is costing you more than you gain.  Here's what I'd do:

- Instead of using `synchronized` to protect your counters I'd use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to reduce the amount of locking between threads.
- Instead of creating and lots of short-lived threads yourself, I'd use a a thread pool (e.g. [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  You can use [`setMaximumPoolSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize%28int%29) to restrict the number of threads being used.  The executor service will provide a queue of jobs.